# iOS 7: Segmentedcontrol won't display image colours

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, uisegmentedcontrol

I got this segmentedcontrol, but it won't display my images right :(
The circles need to be green, yellow and red.
See screenshots to understand :D

If you know what I'm doing wrong or missing please answer :)
Thank you!

This worked in iOS 6..

[image: The green colour for the green circle is chose]

[image: It just display blue circles?]

Comment: are you setting gloabal tint color...? as I could not see your attachment due to network limitation.. please elaborate bit more.

Comment: I don't think i have set any global tint colour.. I just added 3 circles to my project and then chose them, in each segment. And btw. it is not just the circles that turns blue. I tried with some other images, but with same problem :(

Comment: I will see this again when I will be on open network...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under iOS 7 the image is used as a mask and then tinted using the standard iOS 7 tinting mechanism (much like `UIToolbar` icons).

I don't know how to set this up in Interface Builder but the solution in code is to setup each image to be rendered in their original format like so:

```
UIImage *correctImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someName"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Then use this image with the segmented control.

One option would be to update the segmented control in the `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
NSUInteger count = control.numberOfSegments;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    UIImage *original = [control imageForSegmentAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *fixed = [original imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [control setImage:fixed forSegmentAtIndex:i];
}
```